# using an integer in a string to create a dictionary (or list) with that many numbers

Tags: python, list, dictionary, wordnet

so i have this text (wordnet) file made up of numbers and words, for example like this -

```
"09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician"
```

and i want to read in the first number as a dictionary name (or list) for the words that follow. the layout of this never changes, it is always an 8 digit key followed by a two digit number, a single letter and a two digit number. This last two digit number (03) tells how many words (three words in this case) are associated with the first 8 digit key.

my idea was that i would search for the 14th place in the string and use that number to run a loop to pick in all of the words associated with that key

so i think it would go something like this

```
with open('nouns.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:

        words = range(14,15)
        numOfWords = int(words)
            while i =< numOfWords
                #here is where the problem arises, 
                #i want to search for words after the spaces 3 (numOfWords) times 
                #and put them into a dictionary(or list) associated with the key
                range(0,7) = {word(i+1), word(i+2)}
```

Technically i am looking for whichever one of these makes more sense:

```
09807754 = { 'word1':aristocrat, 'word2':blue_blood , 'word3':patrician }
or
09807754 = ['aristocrat', 'blue_blood', 'patrician']
```

Obviously this doesnt run but if anyone could give me any pointers it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> L = "09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician".split()
>>> L[0], L[4::2]
('09807754', ['aristocrat', 'blue_blood', 'patrician'])

>>> D = {}
>>> D.update({L[0]: L[4::2]})
>>> D
{'09807754': ['aristocrat', 'blue_blood', 'patrician']}
```

For the extra line in your comment, some extra logic is needed

```
>>> L = "09827177 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician 0 013 @ 09646208 n 0000".split()
>>> D.update({L[0]: L[4:4 + 2 * int(L[3]):2]})
>>> D
{'09807754': ['aristocrat', 'blue_blood', 'patrician'], '09827177': ['aristocrat', 'blue_blood', 'patrician']}
```

Comment: excellent! one more thing, is there a way to stop it after the last word if the whole text line is like this:
09827177 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician 0 013 @ 09646208 n 0000

Comment: @Johnnerz, sure I added it to my answer

Comment: hey, one more small thing, in those lines i want to add anything after the | and have it as another entry in that key, how do i do this?
`09826918 18 n 01 Argive 0 002 @ 09729560 n 0000 + 08804512 n 0101 | a native or inhabitant of the city of Argos`

Answer (score 0):

```
res = {}
with open('nouns.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splited = line.split()
        res[splited[0]] = [w for w in splited[4:] if not w.isdigit()]
```

Output:

```
{'09807754': ['aristocrat', 'blue_blood', 'patrician']}
```